# Multiple rewrite_rules

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having a hard time getting two rewrite rules to work. Right now these links do work:

```
http://domainname.com/blog/something/something/andsomethingelse/
http://domainname.com/blog/
http://domainname.com/leaderboard/
```

If I access, /leaderboard/something, it shows Not Found error page from WordPress blog, ignoring the leaderboard rewrite rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /leaderboard/index.php [L]
```

Comment: you will never be able to see leaderboard because `.` matches anything, so since blog is first, it should always matche the first item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Ignore real files/folders
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .? - [L]

RewriteRule ^blog/(.+?)$ /blog/index.php [L] # WP standard syntax
RewriteRule ^leaderboard/(.+?)$ /leaderboard/index.php?var=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may be what you're looking for.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^blog/(.+)$ /blog/index.php?path=$1
RewriteRule ^leaderboard/(.+)$ /leaderboard/index.php?path=$1
```

Then you can access the pages like so:

```
http://domain.com/blog/something/somethingelse
http://domain.com/leaderboard/something/somethingelse
```

and in the background it would look like this:

```
http://domain.com/blog/index.php?path=something/somethingelse
http://domain.com/leaderboard/index.php?path=something/somethingelse
```

Comment: It's the same as before. Nothing changes.

Comment: @ncla Okay, I have made some changes try that

Comment: Internal Server Error

Answer (score 0):

You should write rewrite_rules like this code:

```
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3&var4=$4 [L]
```

Your writing code matches anything.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want, to match anything. That's how Wordpress created the .htaccess before this, to match anything.